# Excel Formula to Pseudocode

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, pseudocode

Is there any tool out there which will format excel formulas in such a way that they are more easily decipherable?

I need to convert some complex excel spreadsheets people have made to C# applications and sitting there looking at one line excel formulas is relatively troublesome. Primarily I'm looking for something that can rewrite them to pseudocode or a more readable programming language.

The closest thing I could find was http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html but this still does not help all that much.

Comment: Typically I copy them out to notepad where I can add line breaks and make it more readable.  That said, I'd like to think there's a better way.

Comment: http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Comment: Depending on your use case(s) you could rewrite the formulas as custom VBA formulas and make the syntax more "programmer friendly."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sean Cheshire's comment is probably the best answer you're going to get:

[Excel Formula Beautifier](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/)

It has a feature that allows you to convert to javascript.

The one thing it seems to be missing is a feature to do a batch of formulas at once (which would save a lot of time if converting a whole sheet with "Show Formulas" turned on). I added a [request for this](https://github.com/joshatjben/excelFormulaUtilitiesJS/issues/11).

Given how the app works now, if you try pasting a batch into the single-line input field, you may still get a result that's at least somewhat useful. I recommend giving it a try.

Comment: But since it's open source, it's easy to fork the project an made the changes you need.

Comment: It's not in the web page, but the project supports C# also